# Is it possible to have a Windows instance with remote desktop GUI

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have some experience with Amazon's linux instance. But, I need a Windows machine, and I need to manage it with GUI (something like remote desktop or so). Can any body answer me if this is possible and how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is definitely possible, I use it all the time. Just provision a windows instance and then once it is running, right click on it in the EC2 management interface and select "Get Administrator Password".

You will need to specify a private key at launch time, and use that to get the decrypted password.

You can then use any Remote Desktop client to access the machine using this password and the public DNS name.

Comment: Is the GUI possible with Linux too?

Comment: I believe there are open source Linux Remote Desktop clients, but I have never used one.

Answer (score -1):

Windows has Remote Desktop, which allows you to drive through GUI, or else putting on VNC and connect through there.